# Swift 4.2: what does the following declaration mean

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and IOS so there is a lot of unknown. What does the following declaration statement mean?

`private let _digest: (UInt64, UInt64)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **tuple**. Just like how an array has an index for an element, this variable can also be accessed using `.` operator followed by the index.

```
_digest.0
_digest.1
```

However, if you want to access them using using a name rather than the index, that is also possible. (You can still access it using the index)

```
private let _digest: (first: UInt64, second: UInt64)

_digest.first
_digest.second
```

---

For more on [Tuples](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#grammar_tuple-type).

Answer (score 0):

Its a `tuple` that holds two `UInt64`.

Tuple is a group of different values represented as one . According to apple, a tuple type is a comma-separated list of zero or more types, enclosed in parentheses. It’s a miniature version of a struct.

```
let person = ("John", "Smith")

var firstName = person.0 // John
var lastName = person.1 // Smith
```

Also, if needed its possible to access there elements by name instead of index.

```
var person = (fName:"John", lName:"Smith", age:Int())
person.age = 33
print(person.fName) // John
print(person.lName) // Smith
print(person.age) // 33
```

Further, the type of a tuple is determined by the values it has. So (`"tuple", 1, true)` will be of `type (String, Int, Bool)`.

For more information please visit [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a private constant of type [tuple](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html), which contains two UInt64 values.

You can read about tuples and other types in Swift [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html)

An example:

```
let someTuple: (Double, Double) = (3.14159, 2.71828)
```

Usage:

```
print(someTuple.0) // 3.14159
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically doing is declaring a constant variable - because of the keyword `let` - called `_digest` and you are assigning the *type* `(UInt64, UInt64)` to it, which is a *tuple* with two variables of type `UInt64`.